# Efficient way to generate content for a "fake" file-like object in python

Tags: python, performance

In test code, I pass an instance of the below file-like object to a function which normally expects a file. The function uploads the contents, using a series of 8KB read()s.

It works fine, simulates the contents of a file with consistent but changing data ("0123456789abcdef0123...").

Problem is that it is slow and appears to use a lot of memory -- it gets killed by an OOM killer. I guess the 8K strings returned by read() are not gc'd fast enough?

Anyway, I'd rather not increase memory requirements for this test or use a fixed-size pre-allocated string.

Found an old article https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/ which indicates this is the best approach, but please share any ideas about how to do this more efficiently.

```
class FakeFile():
    '''A file-like object that generates a fixed byte stream, so that uploads
    can be verified without having a large file on disk.'''
    def __init__(self, length = 10 * 1024 * 1024): # 10 megabytes
        self.idx = 0
        self.length = length
    def read(self, size=None):
        r = ''
        max = self.length - self.idx
        if size == None or size > max:
            size = max
        r = "".join(['%x' % (c%16) for c in range(self.idx, self.idx+size)])
        self.idx += size
        return r
    def readLine(self, size=None): # - read one entire line from the file.
        return self.read()
    def close(): # - close the file.
        pass
    def seek(self, i, dir):
        import os
        if dir==os.SEEK_CUR:
            self.idx += i
        elif dir==os.SEEK_SET:
            self.idx = i
        elif dir==os.SEEK_END:
            self.idx = self.length - i
        else:
            raise ValueError()
```

Comment: This thing doesn't look like it could be the cause of your problem. Your memory problem probably lies elsewhere.

Comment: Your `close` method is missing a `self` argument.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use StringIO (or cStringIO)? Seems like a reasonable fit for this use case.

Comment: Your seek needs to make sure idx never goes below zero. It would be possible to blow this up. You could keep a tally of the reads that happen for debug, it possible that you've found a bug in something else that isn't letting go of the returned strings.

Comment: Suppose the code did `seek(1000000000000)`. That would blow it up. You may need to error if seek goes over some test sanity number.

Answer (score 0):

Good call, user2357112! This code is not fast but it is *not* the cause of the OOM. Turns out there was a later call in the test that reads the uploaded object into memory to verify the size, and that's what triggers the OOM killer. I changed that GET to a HEAD and just validated the Content-length. Sorry and thanks for reading.

PS: seek(HUGE_NUMBER) doesn't use any extra memory, strings are only generated and returned by read().